# how mobile apps will use OAuth2.0 protocal for authentication in rails

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Kindly suggest me any sites or git for mobile device doorkeeper-OAuth2 authentication.

Here when the link was accessed from mobile device, it will should ask for authentication before showing results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working iOS example app for OAuth2. The example was created to demonstrate OAuth2 with oPro (another OAuth2 provider Ruby Gem). But, it's OAuth2, so it should still be a valid example since both DoorKeeper and oPro implement the same.